# is it possible to use ' ngZone: 'noop' ' for particular function/component in angular?

Tags: angular

am using 3rd party library to generate PPT in Angular(Version 5), the 3rd party library has lot of async calls and promises, so zone.js keeps track of running like more than 50 loops, it decreases the performance of application.

To boost this, for that particular function I don't want to run 'Zone.js'.

How to achieve this in angular, can anyone please suggest/idea to implement this hectic one.

'index.ts' file

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  ngZone: 'noop'
});
```

this disables for entire application , I need to achieve the same for particular function.

Comment: As an option, you can leave all your async calls inside NgZone, but just detach the changeDetector from root component. So it just won't run change detection after each async operation.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is wrap your third party in `NgZone.runOutsideAngular(fn)`.

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

mouseDown(event) {
  this.element = event.target;

  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    window.document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove.bind(this));
  });
}
```

But I recently tried to do this with three.js, but it didn't work that well.

So another option is to tell zone.js to not track certain events.

What you need to do is to create a new file in the src folder called `ngzone-flags.ts`(the name doesn't matter), that you import at the top of your polyfills.ts file.

You cannot have the code directly in `polyfills.ts` because webpack will put all imports at the top of the file, which will make the zone.js import come before the config.

In the `ngzone-flags.ts` file you should have this:

```
(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true;
(window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove', 'touchmove'];
```

This will tell zone.js to not hook these events.

To check if it worked you can use the performance panel in chrome and run in for a while, to then check the callstack for each request animate frame.
There should be no call to zone.js in there.

### Update

There are more configuration variables that you can add.
You can find the complete list here:
https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/MODULE.md

Comment: is it possible to blacklist a function similar to 'mousemove' event ?

Comment: No you cannot. but there are more configuration variables. I've added them to my answer above